# Pass system.getProperty value or value from config.prop file to pom.xml

Tags: java, selenium, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I want to pass one string input from java class to maven pom.xml and im not sure how to do that. I tried storing the string input to properties file, then read it using property plugin in pom.xml and then pass it. but it is not working.

Below is the pom structure

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <phase>pre-package</phase>
    <goals>
    <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
    </goals>
    </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
    <files>
    <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config.properties</file>
    </files>
   
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
config.properties has :
input = QATeam
I want to pass the value of input to pom.xml. Please help.
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<htmlCode>${input}</htmlCode>
</properties>
After running properties plugin, have tried using ${htmlCode} in other plugins but the value is not passing to pom.
```

Comment: The POM is a maven specific file for describing the project and how it is built. Input to your program on the other hand is a runtime thing, which obviously happens later. So your requirement doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I have a string value which is my outcome. I want to pass this to one of the plugins in maven pom.xml. is there any way to do that

Comment: You did not understand me. How can you run your program before you have even built it? It is not possible!

Comment: Or I have a value in config.properties file. Store=1234 I want to gethe value of this Store in pom.xml and use it in one plugin. Is it possible to do that

Answer (score 1):

This *cannot* work. Maven is a build tool so your `pom` only is relevant at build time. While the pom is copied to you jar by default, it is not needed at runtime. So altering it after compilation won't do anything.

If you intend to pass the outcome of a java operation to a maven plugin you would have to start a new maven build (for a different programme) from your Java app. That's possible and you can easily pass your String as a parameter to your build like that:

```
mvn compile -Dyour.string="whatever"
```

and then reference it like that in your pom:

```
${your.string}
```

But remember this will *only* work if you use it for *another* build. A compiled programme can't alter its own build.

Comment: Ok. I have stored a string value using System.setProperty(key,value). By any chance we can read it in pom.xml and use in a plugin

Comment: Or I have a value in config.properties file. Store=1234
I want to gethe value of this Store in pom.xml and use it in one plugin. Is it possible to do that